# Android ListView, table lookup per item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In the audio player app that I am making, i have a screen that has a ListView showing all the songs on the hard drive. Each list item has a toggle button for "Add to playlist". When added, the icon changes to "Added". When relaunching the app and going to the screen, in order to retain the state, I have to do a query for each item to check if its already in the playlist before i can render it in the screen. 
I wanted to ask if anyone had a better idea of dealing with this. SQL Lookup would be done via async task which makes it pointless, in case the user is scrolling very fast.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: sqlite get all... then compare with your current array (not in sql side, just in java side)

Comment: good idea, i worked around by getting the adapter for the list view to tell me which items were available instead. the problem with sql query is that it has to be (ideally) async which makes it difficult. query to the ArrayAdapter was fast(er)